# .net 4.5 software dont work except on the pc i created on it

Tags: .net, wpf

hello i did make a software with .net 4.5 and wpf 
and the software work as charm on the PC i developed it on.
But when i try to install it on any other pc with the same windows (7) and with .net installed on it , i get an error , and it's never lunch

i used windows installer  exporting option . 
Target framework 4.0 
Build option for any CPU

---- used library -- 
WIA.dll
entity.dll
...........

the error log 
.................

```
Problem signature:

  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: egyptair_gui.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 51b83a7a
  Problem Signature 04: System.Data
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4ba1e064
  Problem Signature 07: 14f5
  Problem Signature 08: 2b
  Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentException
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
```

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

any idea will be great 
many thanks in advance

Comment: Is .NET 4.5 installed on these other computers? It isn't by default.

Comment: Yes .NET 4.5 are installed on all other computer and the installer guide any one install the software to install the framework if it's not installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used a .NET 4.5 version of referenced library. Check it on your PC and change refernece to .NET 4.0 version

Comment: No. You wrote that you have references to: WIA.dll entity.dll, probably also others (like System). Probably they are from .NET 4.5 instead of .NET 4.0

Comment: first its installed on the pc i developed it on . secondly how to change it from 4.5 to 4.0 to test if it's working . many thanks in advance

Comment: Remove reference and add it again. Because you have .NET 4.5 installed it will be difficult to check without uninstalling .net 4.5

Comment: well after your last comment i tried to install visual studio on another pc and after that to remove references and install it once again and after i just finish the installation the software work all right on this pc did it's need for any library from the visual studio ???

Comment: many thanks i test it on another installation of new pc and i found it was mysql connector version issue